# Several "build tasks" for visual studio code (python)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

My tasks.json looks like this:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    // A task runner that runs a python program
    "command": "python3",
    "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": true
    },
    "args": [
        "${file}"
    ]
}
```

When I run `ctrl+shift+B` the top panel asks "Select the build task to run", and there's **one** alternative: `python3`. Now if I'd like to add a new build-task (for example a `runspider` command with scrapy), so it's added to the build tasks. How would I go about adding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define multiple tasks in your `tasks.json` by assigning an array of task objects to the tasks property, like this:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "python3",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "python3",
            "args": [
                "${file}"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": true
            }
        },
        {
            "taskName": "runspider",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "runspider"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> runs the default build task, so you might want to set your `"workbench.action.tasks.runTask"` keybinding.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+b",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask"
}
```

Once that is done, you can select the task when you use `workbench.action.tasks.runTask` command, as shown below:

[image: Choose which task to run]

You can also choose your default build task by setting the `"group"` property on the task. Here, in the following snippet, your `"python3"` task will run as the default build task.

```
...
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "python3",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "python3",
        "args": [
            "${file}"
        ],
        "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "always",
            "focus": true
        },
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    },
    {
        "taskName": "runspider",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "runspider"
    }
]
...
```

You can read more about tasks here: [Tasks in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks)

Comment: Thanks! Both alternatives worked, this was really well written and great help!

Comment: VSCode now has IntelliSense in tasks.json and launch.json.